# How to Get Index value from list in C#?

Tags: c#

[image]

I have following code that i am getting a index and value for example 
`index[0] value[0]"example"[1]"example" [2]"example"` i want to access only one index all value at a time

```
foreach (var pair in profession.Professions.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Index + ": " + pair.Value);
}
```

For example: when user will select first item in list box and that item index is `[0]` and value is `[0]1 [1]480[2]749[3]270` i want to show all the value in messagebox.

Comment: "only one index all value at a time" does not make sense. Could you re-phrase?

Comment: Can you please clearify your question? It doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Richard sir i mean when user will Tap a item in listbox i will find that item index and get all the value of that particular index

Comment: You can check for the particular index with an if statement like if(pair.Index == 1) in your loop. What context are you working in? Asp.Net or Windows forms / wpf?

Comment: Deleted. Sorry, was nonsense

Comment: Alaminut sir i am working on wpf

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is only partial and not very clear, I'm giving this a shot based on the image you provided:

```
//Defining the structure like in your example
static List<int[]> rootArray = new List<int[]>{
        new int[]{1,5,7,10},
        new int[]{2,4,6,8},
        new int[]{3,6,9,12}
    };

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Same loop you posted in your OP, only added a .Where after the initial .Select just to get elements with Index == 0
        foreach(var p in rootArray.Select((x,i) => new {Index = i, Value = x}).Where(f => f.Index == 0).Select(x => x.Value))
        {
            //Since this is a List<int[]> your values are int arrays hence you need a loop to display all the values in it.
            foreach(var i in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Hope this helps.